# Is Data encrypted during In-Transit in Azure Data Factory and Databricks runtime?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Is Data encrypted during In-Transit in Azure Data Factory while data movement
and Databricks runtime when data transformation.

Please share artifcats if any to understand the flow.

Thanks,
Mahammad khan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit theses links to learn [**how to ask a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better and faster answer! Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!

Comment: Are you using the Data Flow activity or one of the Databricks code activities?

Comment: We are using Data movement - Copy activity and for data transformation using Databricks notebook activity from ADF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Databricks workspaces, and all associated API calls, are only accessible over HTTPS with TLS.